# How does wordpress multisite manage subdomains?

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I have a Wordpress multisite installed, and would like to understand how the subdomains actually are managed, ie how does my wordpress multisite knows where to find the files/data when a browser request URL `user1.domain.com` ?

I checked the DNS A record and see only the wild card.

I checked the .htaccess, and it looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Protect the htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Protect wpconfig.php
<Files wp-config.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

so I think the .htaccess does not manage the subdomain, or does it?

so then, how does my wordpress multisite knows where to find the files/data when a browser request URL  user1.domain.com ?

Comment: I remember having read Ipstenu explaining how this *magic* works, but cannot seem to find it in WP forums... Neither in her books, which are a great Multisite resource: [101](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/) & [110](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-110/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the load process, WP loads `wp-settings.php`, which calls `is_multsite()`, which checks for the multisite constant defined in `wp-config.php` if it is a multisite install. If it is multisite, then `ms-settings.php` is loaded. Inside `ms-settings.php`, WordPress parses the requested URI to get the domain, and calls `wpmu_current_site()` to set all of the current site constants based on that domain.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am still not clear on the URL displayed: how does Wordpress manage to display a URL as user.domain.com when there is no DNS settings for such subdomain? is that due to the .htaccess settings? or something else?

Comment: @tucson your DNS has to have a [wildcard DNS record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record), any non-existent subdomains will resolve to the same host.